# How to do OTP authentication with ionic react?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am very new to ionic and react. I am tring to build an app which takes phone number to authenticate user. Is there any specific blog or code base I can follow so I can build this component easily?

This is sample screens that I am trying to build.

[image: This is sample screens that I am trying to build]

Answer (score 1):

first you should have an idea on how auth workflow works. then decide which method you want to use for MFA .

is your app serverless?

if yes you can check for serverless implementing MFA method provided by great providers like AWS and Google Cloud.

if your app does have a server from there you can handle it.

i also found following links useful for you .

https://scotch.io/tutorials/multifactor-authentication-in-your-react-apps

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/16/build-react-native-authentication-oauth-2

https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-authentication-in-depth-8d8c2e4ad81b

https://github.com/goibibo-labs/react-native-otp-login